# why does python 3 integer type iteration issue occurs while using "for" loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

here's my code`enter code here`

```
p = input("enter your number") 
q = int(p)
for x in q:
  print(x)
```

after runing it ,the result it gives

```
output-TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is actual [format of for loop in range in python](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html)

```
p = input("enter your number") 
q = int(p)
for x in range(q):
   print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a loop? Perhaps you are trying to print each digit separately?